# Trimming a string to add a special & non-numeric characters

Tags: c#, asp.net

My questions is, how do I trim a string to add special & non-numeric characters. For example in my database I have 1234567890, and I want to convert the string to (123)456-7890 when my page loads? Is this possible? thanks guys!

Comment: What have you tried? What didn't work? What exactly are you having problems with?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Assuming you want the first three digits between `()` and then three digits then `-` then the rest :

```
string input = 1234567890;
string pattern = @"(?<first>\d{3})(?<second>\d{3})(?<third>\d*)";  //
string output = Regex.Replace(input, pattern ,"(${first})${second}-${third}");

// output will be: (123)456-7890
```

Answer (score 3):

```
string pNum = string.Format("({0}){1}-{2}", num.Substring(0, 3), num.Substring(3, 3), num.Substring(6, 4));
```